# How to stop http post replay behaviour for a REST api built in Java?

Tags: java, rest

I am building a REST API with a POST method which will be called from AWS Kinesis client, all works fine, but sometimes, data gets replayed and stored twice? Any Spring Java suggestions would help my problem.

Comment: I think this question is a rest design problem, in rest we can put api mutitimes, but some biz logic only allow trigger once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is simply hash incoming requests and store them in the user’s session or in a temp table.

Each hash is compared with the list of previously stored hashes with duplicates resulting in an error before the Spring request dispatcher invokes the appropriate handler.

If you don't use a session that use whatever distincts your user and act accordingly.